# How to show products in a new row if the products are more than 3

Tags: oracle

I want to display the first name, last and the product details of the employee.

And if the products are greater than 3 then it should show in a new row.

Sample Data:

```
Employee first name: Emma
Employee last name: Snow
Product 1:Apple
Product 1 Amount:100
Product 2:Banana
Product 2:50
Product 3:Guava
Product 3 amount:40
Product 4:watermelon
Product 4 amount:60
Product 5: Melon
Product 5 amount:30
```

Now as the product are greater than three so the expected result

```
is:
employeefname employeelname product1   product1amount product2 product2amount product3 product3maount
------------- ------------- ---------- -------------- -------- -------------- -------- --------------
Emma          Snow          Apple      100            Banana   50             Guava    40
Emma          Snow          Watermelon 60             Melon    30
```

As watermeleon and melon are product 4 and product 5 so they should come under the same column as p1,p2,p3 but in a new row.

Please help on how can I achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

This is the query I have created.

```
  SELECT emp.first_name emp_fname,
         emp.last_name,
         emp_lname,
         MIN (p1_product_name) p1_product_name,
         SUM (ROUND (p1_product_amount)) p1_product_amount,
         MIN (p2_product_name) p2_product_name,
         SUM (ROUND (p2_product_amount)) p2_product_amount,
         MIN (p3_product_name) p3_product_name,
         SUM (ROUND (p3_product_amount)) p3_product_amount
    FROM employee emp,
         (SELECT employee_id,
                 customer_id,
                 (SELECT product_name
                    FROM DUAL
                   WHERE MOD (rno, 3) = 1) p1_product_name,
                 (SELECT product_amount
                    FROM DUAL
                   WHERE MOD (rno, 3) = 1) p1_product_amount,
                 (SELECT product_name
                    FROM DUAL
                   WHERE MOD (rno, 3) = 2) p2_product_name,
                 (SELECT product_amount
                    FROM DUAL
                   WHERE MOD (rno, 3) = 2) p2_product_amount,
                 (SELECT product_name
                    FROM DUAL
                   WHERE MOD (rno, 3) = 3) p3_product_name,
                 (SELECT product_amount
                    FROM DUAL
                   WHERE MOD (rno, 3) = 3) p3_product_amount
            FROM (SELECT employee_id,
                         customer_id,
                         product_name,
                         product_amount,
                         ROW_NUMBER ()
                            OVER (
                               PARTITION BY employee_id,
                                            customer_id,
                                            meeting_id
                               ORDER BY employee_id, customer_id, meeting_id) AS rno
                    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT rpt.employee_id,
                                          rpt.meeting_id,
                                          rpt.customer_id,
                                          state_expense_purpose_desc,
                                          rpt.default_amount,
                                          prd.product_name,
                                          rpt.amount product_amount
                            FROM state_customer_expense rpt
                                 JOIN product prd
                                    ON rpt.product_id = prd.product_id
                           WHERE rpt.state_period_id = 10001001210627)
                         PIVOT (SUM (default_amount) AS sum_amount
                               FOR state_expense_purpose_desc
                               IN ('1' AS p1, '2' AS p2, '3' AS p3)))) data
   WHERE emp.employee_id = data.employee_id
GROUP BY emp.first_name, emp.last_name
```

Comment: Rather than showing your query only, Please give sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function to number the rows and then, for every 3 items, you can `PIVOT` rows to columns:

```sql
SELECT first_name,
       last_name,
       p1_product_name,
       p1_product_amount,
       p2_product_name,
       p2_product_amount,
       p3_product_name,
       p3_product_amount
FROM   (
  SELECT e.employee_id,
         e.first_name,
         e.last_name,
         p.product_name,
         p.product_amount,
         FLOOR(
           ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
               PARTITION BY e.employee_id, x.customer_id, x.meeting_id
               ORDER BY ROWNUM
             ) - 1
           ) / 3
         ) AS row_no,
         MOD(
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY e.employee_id, x.customer_id, x.meeting_id
             ORDER BY ROWNUM
           ) - 1,
           3
         ) AS item_no
  FROM   employee e
         INNER JOIN state_customer_expense x
         ON (e.employee_id = x.employee_id)
         INNER JOIN product p
         ON (x.product_id = p.product_id)
  WHERE  x.state_period_id = 10001001210627
)
PIVOT (
  MAX(product_name) AS product_amount,
  MAX(product_amount) AS product_name
  FOR item_no IN (
    0 AS p1,
    1 AS p2,
    2 AS p3
  )
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (employee_id, first_name, last_name) AS
SELECT 1, 'Emma', 'Snow' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE state_customer_expense (employee_id, product_id, state_period_id, meeting_id, customer_id) AS
SELECT 1, LEVEL, 10001001210627, 1, 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;

CREATE TABLE product (product_id, product_name, product_amount) AS
SELECT 1, 'Apple',      100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Banana',      50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Guava',       40 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'watermelon',  60 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Melon',       30 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | P1_PRODUCT_NAME | P1_PRODUCT_AMOUNT | P2_PRODUCT_NAME | P2_PRODUCT_AMOUNT | P3_PRODUCT_NAME | P3_PRODUCT_AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Emma | Snow | 100 | Apple | 50 | Banana | 40 | Guava |
| Emma | Snow | 60 | watermelon | 30 | Melon | *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9WHIkXwc)